# Normal distribution probability question

Tags: probability

A survey reveals that the waiting time for the bus during off-peak hours is approximated by a normal distribution, whose mean and standard deviation are respectively 7 and 2 minutes.

Assume that you have waited 5 minutes at the bus stop. What is the probability that you wait for a total of more than 8 minutes before boarding.

any tips? i tried to calculated by 13minutes but answer is wrong.

Comment: It's $P(X>8 \mid X>5)=\frac{P(X>8 \text{ and } X>5)}{P(X>5)}=\frac{P(X>8)}{P(X>5)}$. (Note that they talk about a total of 8 minutes, so that is counting the 5 minutes you already waited.)

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you made is not counting the 5 minutes that the person in the problem already waited, because the problem is asking about the probability to wait for a *total* of 8 minutes. Thus you are asked for $P(X>8 \mid X>5)=\frac{P(X>8 \text{ and } X>5)}{P(X>5)}=\frac{P(X>8)}{P(X>5)}$ where $X$ is normally distributed with the given parameters. Note that this is also not the same as $P(X>3)$, because the normal distribution is not memoryless (in contrast to the exponential distribution).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you tried to calculated by total 13 minutes then you are wrong, as they asked the probability that you wait for a total of more than 8 minutes given that you have waited 5 minutes at the bus stop. So now it's clear that you have to find out $P(X>8\ |\ X>5)$ with mean $\mu=7$ and standard deviation $\sigma=2$.
\begin{align*}
P(X>8\ |\ X>5)&=\dfrac{P(X>8\cap X>5)}{P(X>5)}\\
&=\dfrac{P(X>8)}{P(X>5)}\\
&=\dfrac{Q\left(\frac{8-7}{2}\right)}{Q\left(\frac{5-7}{2}\right)}\\
&=\dfrac{Q(0.5)}{Q(-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{Q(0.5)}{1-Q(1)}\\
&\approx\dfrac{0.30854}{0.84134}\qquad \mathrm{(from\ table)}  \\
&\approx0.367
\end{align*}